# How can i differentiate the types that I created to system types with reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I would like to know if a type that i pass is a system type or a type that I created. How can i know this? Look:

```
// Obs: currentEntity can be any entity that i created
var currentProperties = currentEntity.GetType().GetProperties();

foreach (var property in currentProperties)
{
    if (/* Verify here if the property is a system type */)
    {
         // Do what i want...
    }
}
```

What is the best way to verify that?

OBS: Counts as a "system type" all types of the core standard library, in an assembly signed by Microsoft like: DateTime, String, Int32, Boolean (all types in mscorlib.dll | System.dll)...

OBS2: My entities will not inherit from those "system types".

OBS3: My entity could be any type that I created, so I cannot specify in the comparison.

OBS4: I need to do the comparison without the specifying if the the is equal to String, Boolean...

Comment: Just check for your own properties with "property is yourclass"?

Comment: Define system type. A type in the core standard library? In any referenced library?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is your use case?

Comment: System type, is a type in the core standard library, in an assembly signed by Microsoft.

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni: What do you count as "the core standard library"? Which assemblies, *exactly*?

Comment: For exemple, DateTime, String, Int32, Boolean....

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni what about `FileInfo`, `List<T>`, or `StringBuilder`?  Those are defined in the same place as DateTime, String, Int32, Boolean.

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni What about List<int>?  How about WebRequest or HttpContext?   Just listing examples for us is fine - your code can just test `property.PropertyType` against your list of examples. Done.   However, if you have a *definition* for "system type", please provide us the actual definition.

Comment: @phoog could be too, every type in an assembly signed by Microsoft.

Comment: @PhilipRieck, Ok look to my edit. =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What counts as a "system" type? You could check whether:

- It's in mscorlib
- It's in an assembly signed by Microsoft
- It's one of a fixed set of types you deem to be "system" beforehand
- It's in one of a fixed set of *assemblies* you deem to be "system" beforehand
- (Easy to fake) Its namespace is `System` or starts with `System.`

Once you've defined what you mean by "system", that pretty much suggests the code used to check it. For example:

- `if (type.Assembly == typeof(string).Assembly)`
- `var publisher = typeof(string).Assembly.Evidence.GetHostEvidence<Publisher>();` - followed by a check for `publisher` having the right certificate for Microsoft
- `if (SystemTypes.Contains(type))` - once you've come up with your own list of system types
- `if (SystemAssemblies.Contains(type.Assembly))` - once you've come up with your own list of system assemblies (more practical)

EDIT: As per comments, if you're happy with just `mscorlib` and `System.dll`:

```
private static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<Assembly> SystemAssemblies = 
    new List<Assembly> {
        typeof(string).Assembly, // mscorlib.dll
        typeof(Process).Assembly, // System.dll
    }.AsReadOnly();

...

if (SystemAssemblies.Contains(type.Assembly))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Another possibility: Its namespace is `System` or is nested in `System`.

Comment: @phoog As it's possible to write its own code located in `System` namespace, not sure it's relevant.

Comment: @phoog: True, although that can still be created by the user.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Well, counts as a "system type" all types of the core standard library, in an assembly signed by Microsoft like: DateTime, String, Int32, Boolean.

Comment: @JonSkeet I do noy know how, but.........your answers are just awesome......How did you got all this knowledge?

Comment: There is a way to get all types from core standard library / assembly to do this comparison: (SystemTypes.Contains(type)) or (SystemAssemblies.Contains(type.Assembly))?

Comment: @ken2k and Jon good point about faking System types.  I was mainly thinking about types in Microsoft assemblies that are in a `Microsoft...` namespace.

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni: As mentioned in question comments, you'd need to define *precisely* which assemblies you mean by "core standard libraries" - not just give examples, but give a comprehensive list. For example, do you need any assemblies which aren't included in the client profile? Or perhaps just mscorlib.dll and System.dll? You need to be precise - not just in communication, but in your *thinking* - at which point it's reasonably straightforward.

Comment: @AfnanBashir: I pick things up here and there - but really it's not a matter of knowledge as much as the ability to pass it on. I appear to do quite well on the communication front, although I couldn't tell you exactly how or why...

Comment: @JonSkeet, ok. In that case, only in mscorlib.dll and System.dll.